# Gitlab: automatically close issue via commit not working

Tags: gitlab

in my new project I can't close Gitlab issue's automatically via commit. this is what I try to do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "close #32"
git push origin develop
```

in my previous project when I try this codes, issue closed automatically in Gitlab.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the feature is disabled from GitLab for certain reason.

Go to GitLab -> Your Project -> Settings -> Repository and see the below screenshot. As seen, the checkbox needs to be enabled in order to avail the auto close functionality based on the reference in the commit message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the commit closing the issue is not the *very first* commit.
As documented in [gitlab-org/gitlab-foss issue 54722](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/54722), it would not work. By design.

Check if another new commit, with the same comment, works better.

If not, check the GitLab server log for any error mentioning a failure to process the commit comments.

Comment: if GitLab commands cannot commit to process those critical comments, not confirming their cryptic clause, that would communicates a careless lack of control. Thank you https://www.poem-generator.org.uk/?i=itjh8dq

Comment: yes the issue is not very first commit. I don't understand this "Check if another new commit, with the same comment, works better."

Comment: @behrad I meant, does the issue persist even if you make an additional commit, with the same comment: is the issue still not closed?

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I'm so sorry for delay... yes I commit it again with same comment but the problem still exist. how can I check Gitlab server log?

Comment: @behrad Are you using an on-premise GitLab, or the public gitlab.com?

Comment: I am using gitlab.com

Comment: @behrad Then that would be an issue to report directly to their support: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues

Comment: I heard that you can turn on or off auto-close issue, but I don't know where I can find this do you know where is it?

Comment: @behrad Correct. That would be right there: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#disabling-automatic-issue-closing

Comment: @behrad Or one might have change the issue closing pattern: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/issue_closing_pattern.html (but I doubt it is the case on gitlab.com itself)

Comment: I read this before https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#disabling-automatic-issue-closing but I can't find where to find that checkmark button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224335/discussion-between-vonc-and-behrad).